# Camera facing backwards when exported as FBX and imported to Fusion 7

Tags: export, external-applications

Similar to [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18478/1853) question: I exported a motion tracked camera and some geometry from blender to be opened in Fusion 7. I used the FBX exporter using the default settings (-Z Forward, Y up).

Scene in Blender

[image]
When I opened in Fusion, the geometry came in fine but the camera was facing backwards.

Scene in Fusion
[image]

I tried playing with the settings for Forward and Up on the blender exporter, that changes the orientation of the geometry, but not that of the camera's orientation in regards to the scene.

How can I get my camera facing the right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the right settings for the camera into Fusion7 I found I had to use version 6.1 ASCII of the FBX exporter.

[image]

Now my tracked camera and geometry match the blender file :)

[image]

Comment: Ahem. God helps those who help themselves.

Comment: Maybe someone one else will find it useful... Or show me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Yeah it's totally fine. i just thought it was funny that i'm not the only one who does it http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16624/how-do-i-get-constraints-to-work-in-game-engine

Comment: @cegaton What version of fusion you use? It would be nice, if you could add this to your answer, because with this we can definitely say: we have to use ASCII 6.1 to make it work for Fusion 6 or 7.