# Animation flipped 180 degrees in Unity with .fbx export

Tags: animation, export, bones, unity

I don't know if the problem is in Unity or in Blender. I'm asking both communities.

When exporting an armature animation from Blender with .fbx format and playing it in Unity, it always flips the model 180 degrees before playing it. It sometimes also moves the model to the origin. Both issues shown in the picture below.

Any idea what causes this and how to fix it? I've spent hours trying all kinds of things. The flipping issue I was once able to solve by adding a keyframe to frame 0 that contained the location, rotation and scale data, but that only worked once.

[image]

Comment: Maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20859/camera-facing-backwards-when-exported-as-fbx-and-imported-to-fusion-7

Comment: Thanks, I did quickly try the 6.1 ASCII export actually, but then the model didn't seem to import at all. I'll try it some more later though, I may have made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like it's caused by the existence of LocRotScale keyframes in Blender, i.e. keyframes related to the objects rather than the bones. It can be cleaned up either in Blender if possible, or those keyframes can be removed in Unity from the animation window after import.

Also, exporting with FBX version 6.1 instead of 7.4 from Blender seems to eliminate the flipping problem regardless, but not the origin problem.