# How to export a camera animation to Houdini?

Tags: python, export, camera

Does anybody have ever dealt with camera import from blender to houdini?
Recently I'm dealing with some projects that needs this step but when I do the fbx import, all the settings are completely wrong.

I know the difference between the axis system between the softwares, but also the rotation goes wrong. I didn't manage to find nothing, a constant or a matrix in order to fix this.

Does anybody have an idea or suggestion?
Thanks in advance

---

#### Edit

I manage to get the right position with the format FBX 6.1 ASCII with Y up and X forward but the orientation still doesn't fit. (Blender 2.73 and Houdini 12.5)

[image: Camera in Blender]
[image: Camera in Houdini]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Camera facing backwards when exported as FBX and imported to Fusion 7](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20859/camera-facing-backwards-when-exported-as-fbx-and-imported-to-fusion-7)

Comment: Thanks to you @poor I manage to get the right position, but not the orientation. see the edit

Comment: You can put an empty and also export it. And setup camera to "track to empty" in Houdini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alembic files are the way to go.
Just export from Blender by going to *File > Export > Alembic* and import it in Houdini with *File > Alembic Scene*.