# How to export a scene to Nuke?

Tags: export, camera

How to export animated camera (and basic geometry of scene) from Blender to Nuke?

For example I want to create a ship in the ocean in Blender and to add a people to the ship , using Nuke. I definitely need to add people to the ship in Nuke, not in Blender.

How to transfer animated camera (and the scene) from Blender to Nuke ? In scene I need only basic geometry, (texture, etc. not important).

---

I tried to use FBX, 6.1 ascii version of the exporter (thanks to @cegaton for help), but in this case, the camera was looking in the wrong direction. In Nuke, in the camera settings I turned on "Compute rotation", then the camera began to look almost in the right direction, but still wrong.

For the test, I used a simple scene with an animated cube and animated camera.
https://youtu.be/RMTmptv-Suc - **VIDEO TEST (Blender and Nuke)**

First Frame in Blender and Nuke:
[image]
[image]

Comment: So far, the only way that I found - export from Blender to Maya, and from Maya export FBX ascii to Nuke. Many thanks to Cegaton for advise to use ascii FBX.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [FBX import-export](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Autodesk_FBX) plugin. Try to export the scene as **FBX 6.1 ASCII** - this should work immediately. Go to *File > Export > FBX*.

[image]

Load it into Nuke via *ReadGeo* and *Camera Nodes* and plug both into a *Scene Node*. Don't forget to to enable **compute rotation** in the camera property panel.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I tried it, in the end I got just the object, without a camera. I also tried to use the same fbx in "read a camera from a file" in the camera settings. In this case, I got a static camera.

Comment: Try using the 6.1 ascii version of the exporter. see http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/20860/1853

Comment: Wow! Thank you, it works almost perfectly! But the camera looks a little bit in the wrong direction, I added video and screenshots to the question.

Comment: So far, the only way that I found - export from Blender to Maya, and from Maya export FBX  ascii to Nuke.

Comment: @MaximVelichkin works fine, also camera animation, don't forget to enable **compute rotation** in nuke's camera panel.

Comment: @MaximVelichkin see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1GyM.png

Comment: @poor just to have a useful answer for others down the line. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much, @cegaton, @@poor, for so great and detailed response! :) But, for some reason, in my case it does not work. I exported the scene as FBX, with exactly these settings via the menu Export, but in Nuke camera still looking in the wrong direction (compute rotation turned on). I added in the description above screenshots from Blender and Nuke, and video illustration of camera animation.

Maybe I understood you wrong?  FBX import-export plugin - is menu export in Blender? http://www.pixentral.com/show.php?picture=1X6DoYHiOGgnMHsLKHoLfYDfpJJPo0

Comment: @poor Sure, here it is: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35857
I tested it in Nuke 9.0

Comment: @poor double check works as unchek, in this case the camera is rotated in a completely wrong direction.

Comment: @MaximVelichkin Works great for me, same result in nuke, see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FOJPV.jpg - I meant check it 3 times to update it.