# what is the proper way to transfer camera data from Nuke to Blender and vice versa?

Tags: camera

Does anyone know how to transfer camera from Blender to Nuke and vice versa ? i tried some script but still not accurate , like focal length not properly match etc.

Thanks

Comment: This is indeed very tricky, the last time I tried lots of things went wrong, but the focal length and other camera parameters were correct. Try using an fbx, maybe you can find some more information [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29185/how-to-export-a-scene-to-nuke)

Comment: Since blender supports [alembic](http://www.alembic.io/) now, it's dead easy. Just make sure you've got *Ogawa* selected when saving from nuke. I'm going to update the other answer...

Comment: @p2or Thanks i tried that alembic and works great. The only bug i found is when exporting the animation start  from frame above frame 1000, for every 1000 frame it will add 1 frame. For example my animation start from 20245, then when i load it in blender , the  animation will start rom 20265. so better to start from 1. Another issue if i set the camera as a child of an axis. WHen bring it into Blender, i have to repeat the parent process.

Comment: I tried exporting my camera from nuke to blender using alembic (.abc) but I don't know why my camera animation has increased. Camera Track is 287 frames but when I import the alembic file it is 350. Please help me with this if you know the solution