# Import fbx from Nuke/ Maya and have the correct orientation

Tags: import, .fbx

What is the proper way to import fbx from Nuke ? Does anyone has a successful experience ? I always fail to orient the scene properly. The best setup is to set *FORWARD* to **-Z forward** and set *UP* to **Y up** but the X axis is always reversed. Any trick for this ?

Thanks

Comment: related? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20859/camera-facing-backwards-when-exported-as-fbx-and-imported-to-fusion-7/20860#20860

Comment: No, i'm imported to Blender, not export. There's no ascii option in blender import fbx setting. Also when i write fbx out from Nuke and set as ascii, Blender will throw error saying "ascii in not supported...." . I'm using blender 2.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a way to fix the rotation , this is my setup in fbx import parameter :  turn on manual orientation and set forwar to -Z forward and up to Y up. Then DO NOT use the camera directly , but used it as reference only. Create a new camera, go to constraint property and choose 'child of' and select the original camera as parent. now clear out all translation/rot/scale of the new camera and set X and Z rotation to 180. Now i can see through the new camera.