# Can tracking data from Blender be exported to use in Fusion?

Tags: tracking

I’m new to blender and resolve and was curious if it’s possible to do the tracking in blender and then send tracking data in some way to resolve to use in fusion? If so, how?

Comment: Have you tried alembic or fbx already?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20859/camera-facing-backwards-when-exported-as-fbx-and-imported-to-fusion-7